# c++ console output display on screen

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cout

I'm new to c++. I'm using visual studio 2010 professional. I tried to run this code and it worked fine but the issue is in displaying large output.

```
int main(){
    for(int i=0;i<=10000;i++) 
       print<<i;
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to output numbers from 1 to 10,000, only last 500-1000 numbers are displayed on the console. How can I view all the numbers on screen? If I reduce the number of times the loop executes it displays all the numbers.

Can I resolve this problem using console or I have to adopt some other method?

Comment: That's the complete code?

Comment: Console has a certain buffer, but that is not really a programming question, i.e. off-topic for SO. You can always print this into a file, or with another delimiter rather than new line.

Comment: Increase the buffer size of your console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to increase the size of your console buffer, but that is not really on topic on SO. You can find a thorough explanation for that in [here](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/13919-windows-7-increase-the-buffer-size-of-the-command-prompt) though.

For your convenience, here are the steps inline:

> 1) Click on Start > Run > cmd
>
> 2) Right click on the command prompt window > Properties
>
> 3) In the "Option" tab, modify the value next to the "Buffer size" entry

[image: buffer size setting]

The closest you get with programming and on topic with SO is using a delimiter like ',' instead of new lines or writing into a file.

#### ',' delimiter

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10000) 
        cout << i++ << ", ";
    cout << i;
    return 0;
}
```

#### writing into a file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("example.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        myfile << i << endl;

    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Then, you can simply run `cl.exe main.cpp` to build the application on command line

Answer (score 1):

The buffer for the console has limited size. Though you can change it. Right click on it and choose "Properties".